# error message with scala installation

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I would like to install scala 2.8.1. I used exactly all the steps from 
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/310 but when i write 'scala' in the command prompt then i have the following error
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Do you know whats going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

As the error message is pointing out, java is missing. You have to install a JRE or JDK and make Scala find it, for example by setting JAVA_HOME to the JRE/JDK.

Have fun with Scala